# Jquery mouseover firing click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive got a select menu and i want on mouseover to fire a click event,

I've got this

```
$('.selectMenu').live('mouseover', function() { $(this).click(); });
```

but it doesnt seem to be grabbing the right values. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what are trying to do with the click?

Comment: @Ascherer - I think we need a bit more information.  What function have you bound to the click event? And is there a reason that you couldn't simply bind it to the mouseover event as well? What do you mean by "not grabbing the right values"?

Comment: ok, so im using the jquery selectmenu plugin, and i guess im assuming that there is an onclick on the element that gets the menu to show up. According to chromes inspector, it does have a click listener on it

Comment: looked at the examples here http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html and none of them have class named 'selectMenu'. I see 'ui-selectmenu'. Are you sure you are associating the mouseover handler to the correct element?

Comment: .selectMenu is my own class i threw on it, but it doesnt work with .ui0selectmenu either

Comment: I guess you'd better find out a way to tell selectmenu to show submenus on hover instead of hacking the hover into triggering a click..

Comment: yeah, looking like thats the only way

Comment: have you tried using `.bind()` instead of `.live()`? Just for testing, the functionality is a bit different. Try also debugging with something more visible: `$('.selectMenu').css('background', '#f00')` and `$('.selectMenu').live('mouseover', function() { $(this).css('background', '#f00'); });` to see in which part the execution fails.

Comment: its actually a mousedown event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
$('.selectMenu').live('mouseover', function() { $(this).trigger('click'); });
```

Comment: that's right, remember that the `.click(callable)` method is used to associate a callable to the click event, NOT to trigger a click (for that, there is the `.trigger()` method..)

Comment: @redShadow - It can actually be used for both.  If you don't pass a function, it will trigger the click event.  Minus the parameter, `.someEvent()` is just a handy shortcut for `.trigger('someEvent')`

Comment: .oops, I just found out that `click()` without arguments calls `trigger('click')`, so it should be correct, although I don't like that way at all (it's a bit unclear imho)

Comment: haha, well, either way, turns out, its triggered on a "mousedown" even not a click, so i fixed it there

Comment: ..did you try the Ender solution too? It seems to be the cleanest (a.k.a. "Good") way to do what you need (if it does work, of course)..

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with this, as I was at one point tasked with making the [fgMenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) (which is made by Filament Group, the same group as the people who make the [selectmenu plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) you are using).

The problem is that this plug-in creates elements which are then substituted for your original `<select>`, so monitoring for events on that original element will not help you.  In my case, I had to modify the plug-in source to change the triggering event from click to hover.

Looking at the current source of the plug-in (which you can [find here](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js)) and using some knowledge of how the rest of jQueryUI works, you may be able to invoke the open of the menu by doing something like this:

```
$('.selectMenu').live('mouseover', function() { $(this).selectmenu('open'); });
```

As a disclaimer, I haven't verified that this actually works, but it's the best guess I can make.

Comment: there is a method for open yeah, but it doesnt do anything when i call it sadly

Comment: Hm, that's lame. Looks like you found a good solution at any rate.  This is a cool little plug-in, I hope they keep working on it and making it a little easier to use :)

Comment: yeah, ur solution wouldve been better had the method actually been working lol. Thanks for the help