# Change click event to mouseover when mouseover event already exists

Tags: jquery, triggers

I've already looked at this post : [Jquery mouseover firing click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970885/jquery-mouseover-firing-click)  where the author mentions that he solved it but didn't actually post the solution.

Here's the issue:

Is there any way to alter the code so that it triggers switcher-content on mouseover rather than click?

Here's my example : http://nerotic.net/auxout/

This is the code I was using, including my animating the switcher-content panels until the trigger dots are mousedover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jcps.fader(100, '#switcher-panel');
    var timeouts = new Array();
    var cities = ["#berlin", "#wired", "#sicily", "#sterephile", "#dave", "#hometheatre", "#lsd", "#lefsetz", "#musicart", "#videohifi", "#alu", "#unplggd", "#alfa", "#digitaltrends", "#playboy", "#uncrate"];
    var timeoutLength = 7400;

    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
       timeouts[i] = setTimeout("callCity('" + cities[i] +"')", timeoutLength * (i + 1));
    }

    $('.switcher').mouseover(function() {
        for(key in timeouts){  
            clearTimeout(timeouts[key]);  
        }
    });
});

function callCity(city){
    $(city).trigger('click');
}
```

I've tried:

```
$(city).trigger('mouseover');
$(city).trigger('onMouseOver');
```

I then saw some information on jquery live() and tried this:

```
$("a.fb").live('onMouseOver', function(){ 
    $(city).trigger();
});
```

and this:

```
$("a.fb").live('mouseover', function(){ 
    $(city).trigger();
});
```

However, none works.  In all cases the map continues to function in the same way, the click event continues to work and no errors are returned.

How would I continue to have the animation stop on mouseover as well as trigger the click event?

Comment: Mind telling me what you edited so that I can do it properly myself next time? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing click event from doing anything and load the content yourself using jQuery.load?

```
    var loadContent = function(var1, var2) {
      // do loading content here using jQuery.load
    }
    $('.switcher').mouseover(function() {
      var cityName = $(this).attr('id');
      loadContent('#world', cityName+'.php');
    });
    $('.switcher').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('click will do nothing');
    });
```

Comment: what of my code am I supposed to replace exactly?  If I replace it all I lose the auto-animation of the left panels.

Comment: I may have misunderstood something. Do you not want to load the content on mouseover, instead of click event? The code sample that I shared does that and you can do anything you want in the click callback function. If you want to call `callCity` method, then replace the alert with that call.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was amazingly simple...

$(city).trigger('mouseover');

was correct, I just needed to change 'click' to 'mouseover' in the actual .js.